# How to map fields name in jsonb field to another name in object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql

I use Postgres and I have DB with a table that looks like that

```
column - foo
type - jsonb
value - {"baz" : "test" }
```

Please notice that "baz" is not capitalized (pretty much this json document will be in a camelCase).

I have the code in C# (so the naming convention is Pascal Case)

```
public class Foo
{
     [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
     public BarData Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BarData
{
   // ??? What kind of annotation to put here
   public String Baz { get; set; }
}
```

I use entity framework + npgsql to read/write to DB. Unfortunately, when npgsql read from DB, it won't populate Baz (because the naming convention doesn't match)

a) I tried to use [Column("baz")]. However, it's ignored (probably because it's not really a column, but a json tag)

b) I was considering naming the property "baz", but it just shifts a problem to another place in the code (where another mapping needs to be done).

As a result, I am looking whether I missed some way to do it case-insensitive or map the property to the name which comes from json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npgsql driver uses `System.Text.Json` for serializing `json` values. So all you need is to annotate your property with `JsonPropertyName` attribute.

```
public class BarData
{
   [JsonPropertyName("baz")]
   public String Baz { get; set; }
}
```

If your only concern is casing you can use `JsonSerializerSettings.PropertyNamingPolicy`

This is how you change serialization options as of version 6.0 :

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // Customize based on needs...
};
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.AddTypeResolverFactory(new JsonOverrideTypeHandlerResolverFactory(options));
```

Credits to this github [answer](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1107#issuecomment-945126627)

Also worth mentioning that the second workaround won't affect the query generation.